# Error defining explicit operator bool() outside class

Tags: c++, c++11, explicit, explicit-conversion

I have problem defining `operator bool()` function outside the class

```
class A{

public:
    explicit operator bool() const; 
};
```

I am defining the function outside class as...

```
explicit A::operator bool() const {
    ...
}
```

I get this error - `error: ‘explicit’ outside class declaration`

What is it that am doing wrong?

Comment: Remove `explicit` when defining the operator. Declaration is enough.

Comment: Voting to close a typographical error.

Comment: When you get an error `error: 'blah' in situation X` and it is in situation X, try ... removing ... 'blah' ... and ... seeing ... what ... happens.

Answer (score 6):

Just like you're not supposed to write `inline` for the definition if you already wrote it for the declaration, you are not allowed to write [`explicit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) outside of a class definition:

> It may only appear within the *decl-specifier-seq* of the declaration of such a function within its class definition.

So, just remove it:

```
/*explicit*/ A::operator bool() const {
    // ...
}
```